# BigQuery: change date partitioned table to ingestion time partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an BigQuery **date partitioned** table that I want to convert to an **ingestion time** partitioned table (partitioned on _PARTITIONTIME), using the current date partitioning to feed into _PARTITIONTIME. How can I do this?

**WHY?** Because only ingestion partitioned tables can be incrementally loaded to using BigQuery's scheduled query functionality (by using the @rundate parameter as partition decorator)

Comment: Could you let me know what is not possible with column based tables?

Comment: With column based tables you cannot do a truncate/insert load statement into a single time partitioning, using the BigQuery scheduled queryfunctionality  (You CAN do that with _PARTITIONTIME partitioned tables using the partition decorator)

Comment: Usually how is done is that each transfer creates a new table, so recreates the entire partitioned table. This way you don't have to ditch the partitioned data, you ditch the entire table. The old one is automatically expired every time. This auto expiring can be set on the dataset level. It's all automated, and you just make sure to query the new table.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to ditch the whole table, because recreating the full history every day is too expensive (17 TB of event source data). Therefore we use this pattern of truncating and re-inserting an already existing time partition. And as I said, that works with ingestion time partitioned tables but not with date column based ones

Comment: I've added a feature request here, eventually star  & tune in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117641626

Answer (score 2):

One option is to disable the scheduled query first and copy the column-based partitioned table to a ingestion-time partitioned table. Then re-enable the scheduled query. Please follow steps:

1. Disable the scheduled query through the BigQuery UI: [disable option on scheduled query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFuqR.png)
2. Create a new ingestion-time partitioned table (called ingestion_time_partitioned) and copy the column-based partitioned table (called table_column_partitioned) to the new table (ingestion_time_partitioned).
3. Edit the scheduled query to write to the new ingestion-time partitioned table (ingestion_time_partitioned). **Please remember to re-enable the scheduled query and remove the partition field (which is used for column-based partition).**

Copying from column-based partitioned table to a ingestion-time partitioned table will correctly map the column-based partition to the ingestion-time-based partition. And **[copy job on BigQuery is free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free)**. For more information about copying partitioned tables, please see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#copying_partitioned_tables

Comment: Ok, I am going to try that, did not know BigQuery correctly routed the column based partition to an identical ingestion-time partitioned table.

Comment: I guess each column-based partition could be mapped to one _PARTITIONTIME. Hope this works for you :)